# Is there a way to manually expand variadic templates?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, variadic-templates

Visual Studio does not currently support Variadic Templates and the official word is that VS2012 still will not support them.

I've ported my open source project to use C++11 and Variadic Templates are a huge part of that port. This means I can support clang++ 3.1 and g++ 4.5 but not Visual Studio.

So, my question is, does there exist a tool which will let me manually expand my variadic templates (to some N arguments) and check those into source control so that I can have stop-gap support for VisualStudio?

Comment: You could try hook a decent compiler up to the Visual Studio project. ;-)

Comment: Note that also gcc 4.5 does not fully support variadic templates. Full support has only been added in gcc 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a tool to do exactly this (with the new VStudio 2012 C++ compiler not having support, I don't expect to get variadic templates for another year)

It's very basic, but I thought since there might be interest I might as well publish it.

You can download it from my website here: http://mlvdmeide.com/varexp